# Problems with Blockchain API

Tags: api, blockchain.info

Im having problems because when a user pay to a forwarding address, the forward address receives bitcoins instantly, but takes nearly 1 hour to send those bitcoins to the destination address, the real one, and it only calls the API when it transfers to the real one. How can a user deposit the btc instantly? or faster? Thank you!

Comment: What kind of answer do you want to see? OK, do not use this API and use something else. Seems to me that you should have our own engine and do not rely on third-party services. Wanna hire me for this job? :)

Comment: I would like a solution thats the kind of answer I would like to see.

Comment: I have a stand-alone program which transfers all deposits to a bunch of addresses to one another address immediately. But I am not sure that this solution is acceptable for you. This is just a C++ program for windows, not a web-service. My email is in profile.

Comment: Welcome to the Bitcoin Stack Exchange, Christian. Check out the [tour](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help) if you haven't already. I think your question suffers from a lack of detail. Start from the beginning, what are you trying to do? What API calls are you using? A good question will attract good answers!

Answer (score 2):

Blockchain.info's receive API has been all wonky for the past month or two. The forwarding used to be almost instant, but lately it has been taking up to 24 hours for the payment to be forwarded.

Remember that THEY pay the transaction/mining fee for you, so they pay as little as possible which can cause a delay in transactions.

In my opinion you should try another forwarding service that is not free. I suggest you try [Blockcypher's payment forwarding service](http://dev.blockcypher.com/#payment-forwarding). It's very similar to Blockchain's however the mining/transaction fee will be taken from the funds received and you will need to register and create a token.